# Unknown entry in Hosts file (Windows) for geoip.pango-paas.co

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, dns, hosts-file

I was going to add an entry in Hosts file to make it easy to connect with a server. But when I opened the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts , I saw an entry for (changed the real ip to xx below):

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx geoip.pango-paas.co
```

While searching for this URL on google and some other places I found were domain lists (not sure if they were for could be probably for blacklists but not sure) , the IP in the hosts file isn't the one in the DNS entry of that domain. Not really sure why its there and how it got there, found one Italian forum which says could related to VPN (I use Bitdefender VPN and OpenVPN Connect) but still not sure why it would add such entry.
Just want to find how it got there and if it is something malicious need to take actions appropriately

Comment: You need administrative permissions to make entries to this file. So either you made the entry, or your computer is severely compromised.

Comment: @John Yes I know admin privileges are needed to edit it, but some applications that run as with admin privileges are legit as well, in this case if it turns out to be due to Bitdefender (some of their components have admin privileges I believe) then it could be non malicious.

Comment: I would be wary of these apps.  I have entries in my Hosts file (and for many years) and no App has ever altered Hosts.

Comment: It’s probably Bitdefender VPN. A search for “pango-paas” results in Bitdefender

Answer (score 0):

geoip.pango-paas.co is a GEO-IP database, provided freely by Pango PaaS. It is based on the MaxMind GeoLite2 database.

As far as I know, Bitdefender does not tell which GEO-IP database it uses. But it shares data with Aura, the American company that owns Pango. So Bitdefender is certainly a prime suspect.